# how to drag & drop jqueryui properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have used drag and drop jquery UI for drag-drop functionality.

Its working good when I am dropping one below on but when I try to drop below two it drops not correctly.

displays like this image
[Output Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhQiQ.png)

```
$('.header_draggable').draggable({
revert: "invalid",
stack: "0",
helper: 'clone'
});

$('.edit_draggable').draggable({
revert: "invalid",
stack: "0"
});
$('.header_droppable').droppable({
accept: ".edit_draggable,.draggable",
drop: function (event, ui) {
    $(this).find("input").remove();
    var droppable = $(this);
    var draggable = ui.draggable;
    var draggable_class = ui.draggable.attr("class");
    var posofcls = draggable_class.indexOf("edit_draggable");
    if(posofcls === -1)
    {
        draggable.clone().appendTo(droppable);
    }
    else
    {
        $(ui.draggable).removeAttr("style");
        $(this).append(ui.draggable);
    }       
}
});
```

HTML 
    DRAGGABLE

```
<ul class='list-inline audit_container header_draggable elementUl>
</ul>
DROPABBLE 
<div class="D_VH header_droppable draggablemain2 wid501 border ui-droppable" 
 >
</div>
```

Comment: Dude ! where is your html ?

Comment: @TaiwanHotDog added, please check

Comment: jsfiddle or jsbin ?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example